# Creating Roles - insufficient information for romanbican

Tags: laravel

i am using [" romanbican - bicon roles "](https://github.com/romanbican/roles), i don't see sufficient information for the " Creating Roles ",

code is available but i don't know where i paste this code, please suggest quick steps to implement permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I used this same laravel package and simply created a new controller and route pointing to the the following controller methods:

```
public function getRoleAdmin()
{
    $adminRole = Role::create([
        'name' => 'Admin',
        'slug' => 'admin',
        'description' => 'System Administrator', // optional
        'level' => 1, // optional, set to 1 by default
    ]);

}

public function getRoleModerator()
{
    $moderatorRole = Role::create([
        'name' => 'Forum Moderator',
        'slug' => 'forum.moderator',
        'description' => 'Forum Moderator',
        'level' => 1,
    ]);
}
```

I then created a simple view with a button for each calling the appropriate route/controller/method to create either a new moderator or administrator role.  You will see that calling Role::create simply creates a new record in the roles table with these attributes which you could easily perform with a standard DB call to insert into the table.  I used the same approach for creating/deleting permissions.